# silverlight integrated with asp not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have this problem in this scenario:
1-I made a new silverlight project with webapplication hosted the silverlight project.
2- when trying the silverlight project alone, it works very good with no errors.
3-but when trying the 'silverlighttestpage.aspx' the browser opens and a white page appears.and a the silverlight loading circle appears and after reaches 100% nothing is shown.

so can you please help me, I'm newbie in silverlight and asp,btw I have silverlight 4 sdk installed.

here is the html:
``

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/silverlighttest3.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

and the silverlight project like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="silverlighttest3.MainPage"
  ....

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="blue" Height="507" Width="842" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <MultiScaleImage HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,27,0,0" Name="multiScaleImage1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Source/dzc_output.xml"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any distinguishable content in your main view? Could you maybe post your html in your test page?

Give your Silverlight main view a background color (other than white) and make sure that it isn't just blending in with the white background of your empty test page.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Blue">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: no no, the solution have a website that tests the silverlight project,but the main view has nothing except the silverlight refrences.no other contents I've added

Comment: Hey nero, just curious, are you able to see your Silverlight view in your browser now?

Comment: mm,well after i changed the color ,yes ..but there is another problem i have a 'multiscale image' control in the silverlight view,when trying the testsileverlight.aspx its now just a blue square.although when trying the silverlight project alone its works fine.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a different problem that you originally asked. Could you please accept this answer if it worked for you and ask post a new question specific to your new problem? That way when others view this question and your new question, the comments and answers will be pertinent for it exclusively. Thanks!